Minimum Hessian extension
Given a real function $f$ on a hypersurface $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the infimum of $\int_M \lVert H(g) \rVert ^2$ over extensions $g$ of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Here $H(g)$ denotes the ($n$-dimensional) Hessian of $g$, and the norm is the Frobenius norm.
It feels this should be known but I wasn't able to find a reference.
